# Adwhirl crashes on while iAd is loading

Tags: ios, adwhirl

I have implemented the `AdWhirl` to show different network Ads but while it shows the ads on my view and I tap to open the ad it crashes with the following displayed in the log

> -[AdWhirlAdapterIAd helperNotifyDelegateOfFullScreenModal]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9fce850 2012-12-08
>   19:40:27.571 ExerMemosApp[2294:1b203] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[AdWhirlAdapterIAd helperNotifyDelegateOfFullScreenModal]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9fce850'

I searched too much but couldn't find solution. Give me suggestion to remove this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the `AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter+Helpers.h` file is included in your project? Make sure everything under `AdWhirl/Internal` is correctly referenced in your build settings.

Comment: Yeah that was miss but i use my hack and put all the delegate method in calling file But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

you are not having `helperNotifyDelegateOfFullScreenModal` method in your File. Check that one because the name says, its delegate method. you might forgot to implement that method

Comment: I searched and found in AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter+Helpers.h file but call is not going to method only crash occuers. After that i have implemented the method adWhirlWillPresentFullScreenModal method which is delegate method of AdWhirl but response was same. Please tell me what to do.